# HTML email - GMAIL display block doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, media-queries

I've been creating a HTML email campaign that has to be responsive.
On desktop, the email has 2 columns, but on mobile it has to display them as 1 column.

This is working in other clients as expected, but in Gmail, the column (td) doesn't go full width (image attached).

So the structure is something like this:

```
<table class="w640">
  <tr>
    <td class="w640">COLUMN 1</td>
    <td class="w640">COLUMN 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then the CSS is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 639px) {
 table[class=w640], 
 td[class=w640] { width:90% !important; display:block !important; }
}
```

This is what is happening in Gmail. The 2 columns are not going 100% width: [image]

Comment: What do you mean? If I can't transform the cells into blocks, how can I convert 2 columns (td) into just 1?

Comment: how should I change it?

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but I don't really understand what should I add to the tr.

Comment: `table[class=w640] > tr`, add that to your media query above

Comment: I tried that, but if I give a ´display: block´ to ´tr´, it will display 2 columns on mobile, instead of 1

Comment: it shouldn't as you have also given tds a width of 90% so they should become rows - https://jsfiddle.net/6k5ohkzh/1/

Comment: No... giving `width:100% !important; display:block !important;` to tr just makes 2 columns on mobile

Comment: You obviously have overriding styles as it works in the fiddle - don't use important everywhere, makes your code impossible to maintain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be that you didn't assign a width to your table.
You can either give this a static (px) or a flexible (%) width.

Display block on td & tr should do the job for you then.
hope that helps you out a bit.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 639px) {
  tr td {
    display: block;  /*neccasary*/
  }
}

td {
  background: blue;
}
table {
  text-align: center;  
  width: 90%;  
  background: red;  
  margin: 0 auto;  
}

div {
  background: yellow; 
  width: 400px; /*neccasary if table is given a percentage*/
  height: 400px; 
}
```

```html
<div>
<table class="w640">
  <tr>
    <td class="w640">COLUMN 1</td>
    <td class="w640">COLUMN 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have what seems to be exactly the same problem and was looking for a solution. I already had a width specified for the table, so it wasn't that.

In the end I used `<th>`'s instead of the `<td>`, and now it works!

Hope this helps someone.